# How to quickly convert lots of data to string?

Tags: python, string, numpy

Say I've got the following class:

```
import numpy as np

class ToStringify():
    DEMARCATION = "::::"
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_np_array = np.random.rand(30, 30, 30)
        self.second_np_array = np.random.rand(30, 30, 30)
        self.some_string = "string"
        self.some_int = 5

    def to_str_format(self) -> str:
        entries = [
            self.first_np_array, self.second_np_array, self.some_string, self.some_int
        ]
        return f"{self.DEMARCATION}".join([str(entry) for entry in entries])
```

I've profiled my code and the `to_str_format` takes about 25% of my total program running time. Unfortunately, `to_str_format` needs to output a string (whatever demarcation I choose) that will be consumed further down in some pipeline that I cannot change. I'm doing a list comprehension to try and speed things up, but other than that I'm not sure what else I can do (if at all). I'm using python 3.9 if that changes anything

Comment: I'm more than happy to add more details or clarification but at this moment I don't know what to add that would be helpful. re: close flag

Comment: I don't think your question needs more details or clarity…and also that the way you're doing things is probably the fastest way to convert several dissimilar things into the string format you want. Why are you trying to optimize this — is it a bottleneck in your program? [*Premature optimization is the root of all evil.*](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: > Why are you trying to optimize this — is it a bottleneck in your program

It's the top one (25%) compared with the second (19%) . And yeah, I was worried this might be the fastest

Comment: Well, aside from a few things that I suspect would only be relatively minor tweaks — most shown in the @sj95126's answer, the only other thing I can think of is why have this processing done by via a `class` when a simple function would suffice.

Comment: Ahh, I should have been clear about this but there are other methods in the class too. I just didn't want to bog people down with (seemingly) unnecessary complications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to profile again to verify if any of these suggestions make a big enough difference to matter, but quick informal testing shows maybe a 10-15% improvement, so  it may be helpful.

First, this:

```
join([str(entry) for entry in entries])
```

The `[` `]` aren't necessary. `join()` can consume a generator expression, so a list comprehension just adds overhead of creating a (potentially large) object. So:

```
join(str(entry) for entry in entries)
```

may be a little faster (seems about 5%). Even faster than that (about 10%) would be:

```
join(map(str, entries))
```

Second is the f-string. If you aren't modifying or changing the representation of `DEMARCATION` at all, this is sufficient:

```
self.DEMARCATION.join(....)
```

which avoids the overhead of processing the f-string. All together, this may be the most efficient form:

```
return self.DEMARCATION.join(map(str, entries))
```

One additional thing is the `entries` list. If `to_str_format()` is called many times, and if `entries` never changes (that is, it's always a list of those 4 objects), then it's better to set it once elsewhere (e.g. an instance or class attribute). It may also be slightly faster to create it as a tuple rather than a list.

Comment: Perfect! This did speed up the code. Thank you very much!

Comment: @IanQ: Glad it helped! If you're willing, it might be worth updating the question with some before and after timings that show the speedup from the techniques for anyone else searching for the same problem.